# Resizing my /dev/sda1 partition

Tags: partitioning

I have a problem with partitioning my hard drive. I only have Ubuntu installed but I cannot partition with g-parted while being on Ubuntu. I want to decrease the size of my partition to make space for installing Linux Mint. What do i do? I already have one partition called /dev/sda1 but I'm unable to make it smaller. I already deleted my swap partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to boot Ubuntu live from any removable media then you'll be able to use gparted normally